# Question regarding the indexes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the definition of Schwartz space

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I was asked to prove that the Fourier transform of any Schwartz function belongs to the Schwartz class, i.e:
$$||\xi^{\alpha}\frac{d^{|\beta|}\hat{f}}{d\xi^{\beta}}||<\infty$$
For $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equals a natural number.
After applying the properties of the derivative of the Fourier transform and triangular inequality, i got that the expression above should be smaller to:
$$ k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^{|\beta|}x^{\beta}f}{dx^{\alpha}}dx $$ Where k is a constant.
However, here I have a doubt about the definition, and is if for f to be Schwartz the condition should be satisfy for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belongs to the natural number or only for some specific values. I guess if this hold for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the above condition should be trivial, as I can apply chain rule for the derivative and apply multiple integration by parts to see that the integral is finite. Namely f is a Schwartz function if for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the natural numbers the condition expressed above is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f\in \mathbb{S}$. Then, for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\beta\in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$\left|x^\alpha \frac{d^\beta}{dx^\beta}f(x)\right|<\infty$$.

Next, let $F$ be the Fourier Transform of $f$ as given by

$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$$

Since $f\in \mathbb{S}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|k^\alpha\frac{d^\beta}{dk^\beta}F(k)\right|&=\left|k^\alpha \frac{d^\beta}{dk^\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx\right|\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now, let's integrate by parts, $\alpha$ times, the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  Proceeding, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|k^\alpha\frac{d^\beta}{dk^\beta}F(k)\right|&=\left|k^\alpha \frac{d^\beta}{dk^\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-1)^\alpha \frac{d^\alpha f(x)}{dx^\alpha}\frac{e^{ikx}}{(ik)^\alpha}\,dx\right|\\\\
&=\left| \frac{d^\beta}{dk^\beta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{d^\alpha f(x)}{dx^\alpha}e^{ikx}\,dx\right|\\\\
&=\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{d^\alpha f(x)}{dx^\alpha}\frac{d^\beta e^{ikx}}{dk^\beta}\,dx\right|\\\\
&=\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty  x^\beta\frac{d^\alpha f(x)}{dx^\alpha}e^{ikx}\,dx\right|\\\\
&\le \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|x^\beta\frac{d^\alpha f(x)}{dx^\alpha}\right|\,dx\\\\
&<\infty
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you! Your proof looks fine to me. What I am not sure is if it is ok, to change the order of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, since you started considering f being Schwartz taking the derivative $\beta$ times and end up with the derivative $\alpha$ times. I guess you can assume from the condition for f being Schwartz that the condition should be satisfied for any pair of index $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the natural numbers but I am not sure. Hope you can help me to clarify this question

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, you are correct.  Since $f$ is a Schwartz function, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary (so it doesn't matter that they ended up interchanged).  Recall that $f$ and all of its derivatives decay to $0$ faster than any polynomial.   That is the key.